# Save a list from cvs.DictReader in python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, for-loop

i have a simply csv file like this:

col1,col2,col3
house,55,600
cottage,88,100

I read in this way:

```
with open("house.csv", "r+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as csv_file:
    file_r = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in file_r:
        print(row["col1"])
```

How can I save the result of row["col1"] to a list?

Thanks

I try to save like this:

```
a = list(row["col1"])
        print(a)
```

But I obtained

```
['h', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e']
['c', 'o', 't', 't', 'a', 'g', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `list(row["col1"])` you are converting the string value in col1 in each row to a list.
What you want is to append each value to a list:

```
col1_values = []

for row in file_r:
    col1_values.append(row["col1"])
```